# Alienware X51 & SSD & Kubuntu

Tags: hard-disk, ssd, ubuntu

I have an alienware X51 with Windows 10 installed in a HDD. I plan to buy a new SSD and install the latest version of Kubuntu (16.10 Yaketty Yak) on it. Ideally, I would like to preserve the dual-boot: win10 and kubuntu.

On this regard, I have a few questions:

- Which SSD would you recommend me to buy and from where? (~250GB should be enough; I live in Belgium) Which cables do I need?

Aprox. budget: 300 USD

I would really appreciate any suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I know its an old question at this point, but this answer should still be relevant to someone in need.*

**Crucial MX300 SSD (1TB)** ($239-280 depending on retailer)

> ***The Good*** The Crucial MX300 SSD is competitively priced and delivers fast performance. The solid-state drive uses efficient 3D flash memory and provides strong security with hardware encryption.
>
> ***The Bad*** The drive has a short three-year warranty and trails behind its main competitor, the more expensive Samsung 850 Evo, in performance and features.
>
> ***The Bottom Line*** If you're looking to upgrade your computer's hard drive, the new Crucial MX300 is a speedy and affordable choice.

[Source](https://www.cnet.com/products/crucial-mx300/review/)

Comment: Thank you for the information! I ended up buying the Samsung Evo

Comment: Samsung Evo is a great one, I didn't list that since they tend to be a bit higher on price compared to their competition. I'm glad you were able to find what you were looking for and hopefully this question will help someone else.